# XMLSlurper to parse FXCop results?

Tags: xml, groovy, fxcop, xmlslurper

I'm trying to parse FXCop XML to get a collection of all the "Issues..." tags with the values of their related "Level" attributes. I'm very new to Groovy so I'm stumbling with this one. The schema of the FXCop XML is very complex and the "Issues..." tags can appear at several levels in the schema. I suppose I could "brute force" it and code a separate search at each level but that could ultimately be problematic for more complex programs that are being analyzed.

Is there a simple (relatively) way to retrieve all the "Issues ..." tags from an XML document without having to manually code GPath searches down each of the subtrees?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding a simplified example (if the xml is complex) replicating your issue and what you have tried yet, would help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FxCopReport Version="11.0">
 <Namespaces>
  <Namespace Name="RWSTestXDT">
   <Messages>
     <Issue Name="Namespace" Certainty="85" Level="Error"></Issue>
   </Messages>
  </Namespace>
 </Namespaces>
 <Targets>
  <Target>
   <Modules>
    <Module Name="rwstestxdt.dll">
     <Messages>
       <Issue Name="NoStrongName" Certainty="95" Level="CriticalError"></Issue>
      </Messages>

Comment: @dmahapatro - I've tried little because I can't seem to find anything that points me in a reasonable direction. I tried to post simplified XML but FXCop XML is so complex it doesn't lend itself to the problem. If you simplify it enough to fit in a Comment then the complexity inherent in the problem doesn't show.<br>Essentially I just want to run the entire tree, find any tag named "Issue" and extract the value of Level. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the xml from your comment:

```
def x = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          |<FxCopReport Version="11.0">
          |    <Namespaces>
          |        <Namespace Name="RWSTestXDT">
          |            <Messages>
          |                <Issue Name="Namespace" Certainty="85" Level="Error"></Issue>
          |            </Messages>
          |        </Namespace>
          |    </Namespaces>
          |    <Targets>
          |        <Target>
          |            <Modules>
          |                <Module Name="rwstestxdt.dll">
          |                    <Messages>
          |                        <Issue Name="NoStrongName" Certainty="95" Level="CriticalError"></Issue>
          |                    </Messages>
          |                </Module>
          |            </Modules>
          |        </Target>
          |    </Targets>
          |</FxCopReport>'''.stripMargin()
```

You can do:

```
List<String> levels = new XmlSlurper().parseText( x )
                                      .'**'
                                      .findAll { it.name() == 'Issue' }
                                      .collect { it.@Level.text() }
```

To get the list:

```
[ 'Error', 'CriticalError' ]
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro. That got me my list:  Error  
 Error  
 CriticalError  
 Warning  
 Error  
 Error  
 Error  
 CriticalWarning  
Now I just have to count by Level value, i.e. Error:5, Warning:1, etc. Should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Just add `.countBy { it }` after the `collect` :-)

Comment: @RichardSchaefer btw answer was provided by Tim. I had minor edits to it. I hope you got all your answers. It will be great if you can accept the answer. :)

Comment: @tim_yates  - so I tried this:  
List<String> levels = new XmlSlurper().parse( fxcopfile )
                                      .'**'
                                      .findAll { it.name() == 'Issue' }
                                      .collect { it.@Level.text() }.countBy{it} and it threw this:  Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.countBy() is applicable for argument types: (ParseFXCop$_run_closure3) values: [ParseFXCop$_run_closure3@636e8707] Possible solutions: count(java.lang.Object), groupBy(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Should I be creating a Map intead of a List so it can hold key:value pairs, or a 2-dimensional list so [0] is the string and [1] is the count?

Comment: Clearly a lightweight. I'm not even a Java programmer. I'm the local Microsoft app dev engineer. I got this dropped on me as a "learning opportunity"...